# JQuery Mobile not executing my entire function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I'm trying to add a listview element based on my QR code. So when I scan one QR code, i take the first value of the array, and add a listview element with the text of the first value, and use a counter and so on. However, it doesn't increment my counter. All i get is that the function appendToList() gets terminated once listview refreshes. Count doesnt increment and ArrayIndex remains empty. How can I get the counter to work? And the array as well? The function doesn't execute all the way.

```html
function scan() {
  cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {
      $("#nullExhibition").remove();
      resetData(); // Removes the empty exhibition text
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        if (result.format == "QR_CODE") {
          var value = result.text;
          if(!localStorage.getItem("LocalData"))localStorage.setItem("LocalData","[]")
          data = localStorage.getItem("LocalData");
          //alert(data);
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          data.push(value);
          localStorage.setItem("LocalData", JSON.stringify(data));
          //location.reload();
          alert(count);
          appendToList();
          // location.hash = '#Vote';
        }
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    }
  );
}
//JJJ Function: creates table which will be refreshed in the homePage //CW Create the listview if not created
function appendToList() { 
  $("#list").append("<li id='" + count + "' style='font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif !important;' class='ui-content'><a href='javascript:pageGenerator()'>" + data[0] + "</a></li>");
  $("#list").listview("refresh");
  ArrayIndex.append(data[0]);
  count ++;
}
function resetData(){
  localStorage.removeItem("LocalData");
}
```

Comment: throw a `debugger;` inside the function in Chrome and to step through. Where is count defined?

Comment: Thing is, I'm have to use the camera to scan so can't go on chrome

Comment: count is a global variable

Comment: It's tough for me to tell where it could be failing, but I would look into ways of debugging that we most likely be invaluable to you later on. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Comment: Aight, thanks I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you declare "count" in the global scope? You reference it in two separate functions, but are neither passing the value between them, nor made it a global var so that both functions reference the same variable. They way you have it, you reinitialize that var each time that you call the appendToList() function.

Add this to the top of your document (outside of the function closures):

```
var count = 0;
```

Comment: It's being declared in the above part of the code. I didn't copy down my globals into this fraction of code.

Comment: Nope, everything's fine. :(